# Calculating the average number in a nesting loop Java

Tags: java

does anyone knows how to calculate the average in a loop. Every time I calculated the average I received 0 or 1.   I know that I need use average = (sum) / (salary_annually);  but I can't get it to work. Thanks in advance.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class midterm 
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int sum = 0;
    int average=0;
    int count = 0;
    int salary_annually = 0;

    for(int employee =1; employee <= 2; employee++)
    {
    System.out.println("Employee: " + employee);

         for(int year=1; year <= 2; year++)
         {

            System.out.println("Please Enter the Salary for Year: "  + year);
              salary_annually = kb.nextInt();

                          sum += salary_annually  ;
              if (min >= salary_annually) 
              { 
                     min = salary_annually;
              } 
             if (max <=salary_annually) 
             { 
               max = salary_annually;
              } 

            average = (sum) / (salary_annually); 


         }

          System.out.println("The average is " + average);
       System.out.println("The higher number  " + max);
       System.out.println("The the lowest number " + min);
     }

   }
  }
```

Comment: AFAIK average is calculated by sum / count.

Comment: The `int` values should be `double` (or promoted to `double`) before calculation.

Comment: average should be calculated outside inner for loop - `average = (sum) / 2;`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it to work. I need to calculated for 5 years. So I just changed it to average = (sum) / 5;

Comment: Hello, I just found that when I calculate the average for the second user, I get a different result.  For example, if I add this number for the first user 10,10,10,20,20. I get 14.0 which is correct. But when I enter the same number for the second user I get 28.0? any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem here is that you are using integer division. Since the sum and salary_annually are both integers division works slightly different. There is not remainder because dividing two integers gives an int.

For example 1/2 is not .5 as you might expect but instead it is 0. Any fractional number is dropped when doing integer math. As another example 9/5 is not 1.8 but instead 1.

If you want the average then you can either declare sum or salary_annually as a double and declare the average as a double as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 average = (sum) / (salary_annually);
```

To

```
 double average=0;// Declare it as `double` rather than `int`

 average = (sum) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. average is calculated by: `average = sum / count;`
2. you need to increment your `count` variable, otherwise you will always get and `ArithmeticException / by zero`

Answer (score 0):

The Average is calculated by `average = sum / count` where average should be of type double.

You did declare the variable count, but didn't use it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calulate {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;
    int count = 2;
    int salary_annually = 0;

    for (int employee = 1; employee <= 2; employee++) {
        System.out.println("Employee: " + employee);

        for (int year = 1; year <= count; year++) {

            System.out.println("Please Enter the Salary for Year: " + year);
            salary_annually = kb.nextInt();
            sum += salary_annually;

            if (min >= salary_annually) {
                min = salary_annually;
            }
            if (max <= salary_annually) {
                max = salary_annually;
            }

        }

        average = sum / count; 

        System.out.println("The average is " + average);
        System.out.println("The higher number  " + max);
        System.out.println("The the lowest number " + min);
    }

}
```

}